# Code in Shell Script runs before other Operations

Tags: bash, xclip

> This same problem is better formulated in [a question posted to the **Unix & Linux** StackExchange community](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316715/how-is-bashs-interactive-mode-related-to-x-clipboard).

I am programming a script which opens on a key press, open a new terminal (gnome-terminal), runs scrot (screenshot tool), saves the picture with random name to a directory, uploads it to pomf.cat and copies the link to the clipboard.

This works fine. What im trying to do now is, when uploading is done, close the terminal.

My script works like this:

Shortcut (PrtScr) -> gnome-terminal -e "python path/to/script.py" -> Start Scrot -> Save File (and remember path to file) -> bash script2.sh path/to/picture -> Upload to pomf.cat -> Get the link -> Put into clipboard via "xclip -selection clipboard"

Since i want to close the Terminal after putting the String into Clipboard, i added this:

```
eval $(printf $link | xclip -selection clipboard && sleep 1 && pkill terminal)
```

The problem with this is, nothing gets copied into clipboard and the terminal closes.

However, without "&& sleep 1 && pkill terminal" the link gets copied but the terminal stays open.

Thanks in advance.

//EDIT

First Script (for running scrot)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import uuid
import time

def rstring(string_length=10):
    random = str(uuid.uuid4())
    random = random.upper()
    random = random.replace("-","")
    return random[0:string_length]

randomString = rstring(16)

os.system("scrot -s -q 100 /home/timon/screenshots/" + randomString + ".jpg")

while True:
    processRead = os.popen("ps aux | grep \"scrot -s\" | cat").read()
    if "scrot -s" not in processRead:
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        break
        system.sleep(3)

os.system("/home/timon/.screenshot_stuff/./screen.sh /home/timon/screenshots/" + randomString + ".jpg")
```

Second Script (for uploading the screenshot)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dest_url='https://cuntflaps.me/upload.php'
return_url='https://a.cuntflaps.me'

if [[ -n "${1}" ]]; then
    file="${1}"
    if [ -f "${file}" ]; then
        printf "Uploading ${file}..."
        my_output=$(curl --silent -sf -F files[]="@${file}" "${dest_url}")
        n=0  # Multipe tries
        while [[ $n -le 3 ]]; do
            printf "try #${n}...\n"
            if [[ true ]]; then
                return_file=$(echo "$my_output" | grep "url" |  sed 's/\,//g' | sed 's/\\//g' | sed 's/\"//g' | sed 's/\url://g' | tr -d ' ')
                printf 'done.\n'
                break
            else
                printf 'failed.\n'
                ((n = n +1))
            fi
        done
            printf "$return_file" | xclip -selection clipboard && pkill terminal
    else
        printf 'Error! File does not exist!\n'
        exit 1
    fi
else
    printf 'Error! You must supply a filename to upload!\n'
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why do you need the `eval`?

Comment: This is for running commands, isnt it?

Comment: Not exactly, it is for adding an extra level of expansion/substitution which seems to be not needed in your case. In fact it is even used incorrectly - it tries running as a command the output of the command inside `$(...)`.

Comment: Try just `printf "$link" | xclip -selection clipboard && exit` (without `eval`)

Comment: exit doesn't close it, pkill terminal kills it before fetching the link.

Comment: Can you replace your description of the script with the actual code?

Comment: I added it in the edit.

Comment: There should be one more (master) script - the one that calls these two scripts. Can you add it too?

Comment: No, the master script is the shortcut which executes the first one in a gnome-terminal. "os.system("/home/timon/.screenshot_stuff/./screen.sh /home/timon/screenshots/" + randomString + ".jpg")" starts the second script, with the attribute, where the path to the screenshot is.

Comment: I was able to produce a simpler test case that is similar to your problem and posted [a question at unix.stackexchanghe.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316715/how-is-bashs-interactive-mode-related-to-x-clipboard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the end i came up with my own solution.

The problem seemed to be xclip itself.
Now i use "xsel --clipboard --input", which seems to work, even after exiting directly.